# Harmonic polynomial of degree 3

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ be a function defined by
$$
\begin{split}
f(x,y,z) = & \,\Big\{a_1 x y z  +a_2\left(-x^3+3 x y^2\right) +a_3\left(3 x^2 y-y^3\right) +a_4\left(3 y^2 z-z^3\right) \\ 
& \quad+a_5\left(-y^3+3 y z^2\right) +a_6\left(3 x^2 z-z^3\right) +a_7\left(-x^3+3 x z^2\right),\\
& b_1x y z  + b_2\left(-x^3+3 x y^2\right) +b_3\left(3 x^2 y-y^3\right) +b_4\left(3 y^2 z-z^3\right) \\
& \quad+b_5\left(-y^3+3 y z^2\right) +b_6\left(3 x^2 z-z^3\right) +b_7\left(-x^3+3 x z^2\right) ,\\
& c_1x y z +c_2\left(-x^3+3 x y^2\right) +c_3\left(3 x^2 y-y^3\right) +c_4\left(3 y^2 z-z^3\right)\\ 
& \quad+c_5\left(-y^3+3 y z^2\right) +c_6\left(3 x^2 z-z^3\right) +c_7\left(-x^3+3 x z^2\right) \Big\}.
\end{split}$$

It seems to me that such function cannot be injective in $\Bbb R^3$ but maybe this is a hard question. Observe that $\Delta f=0$,

Comment: Christian Remling, the image is R^3

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you wish to prove that it is injective?

Comment: Sidharth Ghoshal, I state that none of such function is injective.

Comment: An earlier question on this website showed that no homogeneous cubic in two variables could be injective as a function from ${\bf Z}\times{\bf Z}$ to $\bf Z$.